# Spatial Resolution in Magnetocardiography

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, spectroscopy, signal-processing, atomic-excitation

In the science paper called Development of an optical cardio-magnetometer by George Bison, it is mentioned that spatial resolution of 10-20mm is required for mapping MCG signal(page 52). What does the spatial resolution means here and does it depends upon the number of sensors only or could depend on the size of the sensor also?